# Odd jQuery animate delay

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm working on a simple function to hide a message when a user clicks a close button. The odd thing is that when I use this code, everything works fine except for an odd 7ish second delay. I'm setting a div to transition into 0 opacity over 1000ms and then changing the z-index to put it behind everything after. This all works fine except for the delay on the opacity transition. When using this code:

```
$(".x").bind("click",function() {
    $('#holder').animate({opacity: "0"}, 1000, "easeOutQuart");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#holder').css('z-index','-1');}, 1000);
```

I get an unexplained delay of of about 7 seconds. If I change the code to this:

```
$(".x").bind("click",function() {
    $('#holder').css('display','none');
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('#holder').css('z-index','-1');}, 1000);
```

The effect is instant. Obivously the setTimeout function is overkill with the display but I'm just showing it's unrelated to the timing issue from what I can tell.

Some have asked why not use fadeOut() and there's no reason not to, but it doesn't change the delay issue. Still about a 7 second delay using this code:

```
$(".x").click(function () {
  $("#holder").fadeOut("slow");
  });
```

I've tried a number of things including adding a .stop() call before the animation. While the delay is confusing, the function works as a whole. When you click .x, the #holder div fades (after a delay) and then the z-index is changed to be behind the rest of my divs. I'm happy with the function and method, just confused why it's such a dramatic delay. The only other item I can think to make note of is that the code is all inside a php file and used through 
. Cant think why that would change it though.

Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(".x").bind("click",function() {
    $('#holder').animate({opacity: "0"}, 1000, "easeOutQuart",function(){
        $(this).css('z-index',-1);
    });
});
```

I dont understand purpose of using "easeOutQuart" on opacity property and dont know what effect are you expecting.
BTW, i will suggest you to use `fadeOut()` instead of animate.

**UPDATE**

Not sure what is your issue, but try this maybe, depending of your html code:

```
$(".x").click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#holder").fadeOut("slow");
  });
```

Comment: fadeOut() is the right choise in these types of events. +1 when i can.( reached max votes for the day )

Comment: The above code doesn't change anything about the delay unfortunately.

Comment: What about using fadeOut() instead?

Comment: I don't have anything against fadeOut() but it doesn't pertain to my issue at hand. I modified the post above to show that I've used fadeOut() with the same results. About a 7 second delay.

Comment: I cannot understand why you have a 7 seconds delay. There is something wrong somewhere in your code, maybe multiple handler call. As i cannot see your code, maybe try my update.

Comment: I think the code as well as the new code you put it sound. Nothing wrong with how it is supposed to function. I think there is a bug somewhere else in my site. I appreciate your advice on the issue. I'm not sure what to do with my question but I +1 your response. Thanks again.